# configure angular2 http in packages.json

Tags: http, types, angular

I am trying to write a very very simple app in angular 2 
I need to read JSON file and therefore need `angular2/http`

Applied `npm init` to build the `packages.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "front-end",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": " blah blah",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect": "^3.4.1",
    "del": "^1.2.1",
    "angular2": "2.0.0-beta.16",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.0",
    "open": "^0.0.5",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.2",
    "serve-static": "^1.10.2",
    "systemjs": "^0.19.27",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "www.hello.com"
  },
  "author": "kpmg-dna-fs-de",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

I get the following:

Error: Error: XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:9000/angular2/http.js(…)

from angula2.polyfills. Not sure how to proceed.
The auth0 demo [here](https://github.com/auth0-blog/angular2-http/blob/master/package.json) shows no need to explicitly mention angular2/http in the dependencies.

What is the difference with the use of:

```
"@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
"@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.1",
```

as in [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)
I mean: I get the version number, but why `"angular2": "2.0.0-rc.1"` not work with `npm install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look into Angular CLI way of working with Angular 2 apps, it gives well structured way of development.

Angular 2 modules are loaded using system.js as in quickstart you mentioned or if you CLI.

How ever from your questions i would draw below points.

1. Want to build Angular 2 app -- either follow quickstart link or better use [Angular CLI](http://www.mithunvp.com/build-angular-apps-using-angular-2-cli/).
2. Want to use HTTP way to access data -- use angular2-in-memory-web-api, using this you can load data from JSON file & pass this data to UI using Angular 2 HTTP concept.